# Increase speed of Insert/Update/Delete using ActiveRecord / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm iterating over a collection of updates (which include additions, updates and deletions). I'm currently looping out over these updates, checking to see whether it exists. If it does, updating the information. If it doesn't, creating a record.

This seems to be taking an unpleasurable amount of time. I'd say 1 every 2 seconds, maybe slightly faster. But I've got 60,000 left to process and it's going to take 109 hours (give or take) to complete. Which isn't acceptable.

Is there anyway to perform this more efficiently?

```
Update.all.each do |u|

  product = Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["product_codes = ?", u.product_codes])

  if u.update_type == "Delete"

    daap = DeletedProduct.new
    daap.product_codes = u.product_codes
    daap.date_deleted = timestamp
    daap.save

    if product.count == 1
      product.first.destroy
      puts "Product #{ u.product_codes } deleted"
      u.destroy
      @delete = @delete + 1
    elsif product.count > 1
      product.each do |pro|
        pro.destroy
        puts "Product #{ u.product_codes } deleted (UPDATE #{ u.id})"
        @delete = @delete + 1          
      end
      u.destroy
    else          
      @notfound.push(u.product_codes)
      u.destroy
      @delete = @delete + 1
    end
  elsif u.update_type == "AddOrUpdate"
    if product.count == 1
      p = Product.first
      p.data = u.data
      p.last_updated = timestamp
      p.save
      puts "Product Updated #{ p.product_codes }"
      u.destroy
      @update = @update + 1
    else
      p = Product.new
      p.product_codes = u.product_codes
      p.data = u.data
      p.last_updated = timestamp
      p.save
      puts "Product Added #{ p.product_codes }"
      u.destroy
      @delete = @delete + 1
    end
  end


end
```

EDIT: It's the product lookup that takes so long. Is there anyway to speed up this part of the process? 'product = Product.find(...'

Comment: You could always try writing the raw SQL to do it.

Comment: You could also replace some of the `each` loops with something like [`#delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all) that will be much much faster.

Comment: @RyanE: But `delete_all` doesn't call callbacks so it can cause problems with the usual "no logic in the database" Rails attitude.

Comment: maybe skip callbacks for the save? You could always profile and find out where the bottleneck seems to be...

Comment: What indexes do you have on your table? What hardware is your code on, and is the database on? How busy are those machines? We need more information about your setup because several things could affect speed.

Comment: Indexes. I almost know what they are, but wouldn't know whether or not the DB has any setup. I've not done anything this large scale-wise before. Pretty much jumped in at the deepend due to this project.

The Database is on one of Rackspaces 512mb VPS's, Ubuntu 12.10. The only purpose of the server is to operate the MySQL server. The code is being run locally on my Macbook (2.3ghz Quad Core i7, 16GB DDR3)

Comment: I've attempted to integrate 'activerecord-import', by adding 'products []' at the start and then instead of 'p.save', I've replaced both with 'products << p'. Then running the import at the end of the loop. However this is definitely taking longer to iterate through. I'd say 3/4 seconds a piece..

Comment: I removed the product lookup, and it literally flys so it looks like the fact it's checking each product to see if it exists is the problem. Any way to get around this? A better way to check / update than I'm currently doing?